# While Loop Launching unstoppable Emails - Bypassing Start-Sleep PowerShell CMDLET

Tags: powershell

When I comment out the while loop it runs as it should in connecting to the DB2 database and delivering the result as expected from the IF condition using its threshold limit to fire the email.  But when I include the while loop with the sleep of 5 minutes - it should only receive an email every 5 minutes during this test period.  What really happens is - I need to disable the script in Task Scheduler to halt the flood of emails.

What is wrong with the while loop - do I need a break/exit ?

```
#DESCRIPTION:Notifies Business Systems OF FAILED WORKUNITS
#SYNOPSYS:This script is launched via the Windows Task Scheduler at System Startup and runs continously until halted by a server administrator.
#AUTHOR: 
#REVISION HISTORY:
#INPUTS: none
#OUTPUTS:
########################################################################################################################################
while($true) 
{
#### password vault for encrypted lawson password retrieval 
$vault = 'D:\TEST\figpwd2.txt' 
# retrieve the password.
$securestring = convertto-securestring -string (get-content $vault)
$bstr = [System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::SecureStringToBSTR($securestring)
$password = [System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::PtrToStringAuto($bstr)
$factory = [System.Data.Common.DbProviderFactories]::GetFactory(“IBM.Data.DB2”)
$cstrbld = $factory.CreateConnectionStringBuilder()
$cstrbld.Database = 'DBNAME'
$cstrbld.UserID = 'user'
$cstrbld.Password = $password
$cstrbld.Server = 'SERVER:50001'
$dbconn = $factory.CreateConnection()
$dbconn.ConnectionString = $cstrbld.ConnectionString
$dbconn.Open()
$dbcmd = $factory.CreateCommand()
$dbcmd.Connection = $dbconn
########################################################################################################################################

$dbcmd.CommandText = 'SELECT PFIWORKUNIT,ACTOR,FLOWDEFINITION,WORKTITLE,STATUS FROM LAWSON.PFIWORKUNIT WHERE STATUS BETWEEN 0 AND 3'
########################################################################################################################################

$dbcmd.CommandType = [System.Data.CommandType]::Text
$da = $factory.CreateDataAdapter()
$da.SelectCommand = $dbcmd
$ds = New-Object System.Data.DataSet
$da.Fill($ds) | Out-Null

$dbconn.Close()
# Determine Trigger for Alert - how many occurances
if($ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count -gt 4) {
# Write to Microsoft EventLog the Event which triggers a Cherwell Ticket to BST On Call Queue
Write-EventLog -LogName "TestLog" -Source "TestApp" -EventID 3001 -EntryType Information -Message "testing this Greater Than set to 4 - Email sent"


$exportObject=@() 
     ForEach ($row in $ds.Tables[0].Rows) {

        $ExciterObject = New-Object PSObject
        $ExciterObject | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "PFIWORKUNIT" -Value $row.PFIWORKUNIT
        $ExciterObject | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "ACTOR" -Value $row.ACTOR 
        $ExciterObject | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "FLOWDEFINITION" -Value $row.FLOWDEFINITION 
        $ExciterObject | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "WORKTITLE" -Value $row.WORKTITLE 
        $ExciterObject | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "STATUS" -Value $row.STATUS
        $exportObject += $ExciterObject

        }
        echo $exportObject

        
        function ConvertTo-HTMLTable ($obj) {
    # Accepts a System.Data.DataTable object or an array of PSObjects and converts to styled HTML table

    # add type needed to replace HTML special characters into entities
    Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Web

    $sb = New-Object -TypeName System.Text.StringBuilder
    [void]$sb.AppendLine('<table>')
    if ($null -ne $obj) {
        if (([object]$obj).GetType().FullName -eq 'System.Data.DataTable'){
            # it is a DataTable; convert to array of PSObjects
            $obj = $obj | Select-Object * -ExcludeProperty ItemArray, Table, RowError, RowState, HasErrors
        }
        $headers = $obj[0].PSObject.Properties | Select -ExpandProperty Name
        [void]$sb.AppendLine('<thead><tr>')
        foreach ($column in $headers) {
            [void]$sb.AppendLine(('<th>{0}</th>' -f [System.Web.HttpUtility]::HtmlEncode($column)))
        }
        [void]$sb.AppendLine('</tr></thead><tbody>')
        $row = 0
        $obj | ForEach-Object {
            # add inline style for zebra color rows
            if ($row++ -band 1) {
                $tr = '<tr style="background-color: {0};">' -f $oddRowBackColor
            } 
            else {
                $tr = '<tr>'
            }
            [void]$sb.AppendLine($tr)
            foreach ($column in $headers) {
                [string]$val = $($_.$column)
                #PowerShellv5 -  if ([string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($val))#
                if ($val -notmatch "\S") { 
                    $td = '<td>&nbsp;</td>' 
                } 

                else { 
                    $td = '<td>{0}</td>' -f [System.Web.HttpUtility]::HtmlEncode($val)
                }
                [void]$sb.Append($td)
            }
            [void]$sb.AppendLine('</tr>')
        }

        [void]$sb.AppendLine('</tbody>')
    }
    [void]$sb.AppendLine('</table>')

    return $sb.ToString()
}


$headerBackColor = '#4F81BD'  # backgroundcolor for column headers
$oddRowBackColor = '#DCE6F1'  # background color for odd rows

$style = @"
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
    <title>Report</title>
    <meta name="generator" content="PowerShell" />
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <style type="text/css">
    body {
        font-family: Verdana, Arial, Geneva, Helvetica, sans-serif;
        font-size: 12px;
        color: black;
    }

    table, td, th {
        border-color: black;
        border-style: solid;
        font-family: Verdana, Arial, Geneva, Helvetica, sans-serif;
        font-size: 11px;
    }
    table {
        border-width: 0 0 1px 1px;
        border-spacing: 0;
        border-collapse: collapse;
    }

    td, th {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 4px;
        border-width: 1px 1px 0 0;
        text-align: left;
    }
    th {
        color: white;
        background-color: $headerBackColor;
        font-weight: bold;
    }
    ol.nobull {
 list-style: none;
}

    </style>

<p><span style="color: #0000ff;"><strong>Testing for Today</strong></span></p>
<p><span style="color: #0000ff;"><strong>WORK UNIT STATUS LEVELS BELOW:</strong></span></p>
<ol class='nobull'>
<li>01 = (<span style="color: #3366ff;"><strong>Ready for processing</strong></span>).</li>
<li>02 = (<span style="color: #3366ff;"><strong>Processing in progress</strong></span>).</li>
<li>03 = (<span style="color: #3366ff;"><strong>Processing failed</strong></span>).</li>
<li>04 = (<span style="color: #3366ff;"><strong>Processing completed</strong></span>).</li>
<li>05 = (<span style="color: #3366ff;"><strong>Cancellation requested</strong></span>).</li>
<li>06 = (<span style="color: #3366ff;"><strong>Cancellation in progress</strong></span>).</li>
<li>07 = (<span style="color: #3366ff;"><strong>Cancellation failed</strong></span>).</li>
<li>08 = (<span style="color: #3366ff;"><strong>Cancellation completed</strong></span>).</li>
</ol>
"@
####SET EMAIL VALUES####
$bodyA = '{0}</head><body>{1}</body></html>' -f $style, (ConvertTo-HTMLTable $exportObject)
$EmailTo = "MYEMAIL@COMPANY.org"
$EmailFrom = "BSTAlert@COMPANY.org"
$Subject = "Failed Work Unit Issue - High Priority" 
$Body = $bodyA 
$SMTPServer = "mail.COMPANY.org" 

####EMAIL PROCESS ####
$anonUsername = "anonymous"
$anonPassword = ConvertTo-SecureString -String "anonymous" -AsPlainText -Force
$anonCredentials = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential($anonUsername,$anonPassword)
Send-MailMessage -smtpserver "$SMTPServer" -from "$EmailFrom" -to "$EmailTo" -subject "$Subject" -bodyAsHtml "$Body" -credential $anonCredentials

}

Start-Sleep -Seconds 300
}
```

Comment: I assume when you're running it on the loop you don't have the Start-Sleep line commented out like it is in your example here? It would be useful to see the non-working version of the code with the loop enabled, rather than the commented out version that does work, so we can see it in the state where it's not working.

Comment: thanks - Keith, I forgot to uncomment this out - this was my test that everything worked on a single run - hence the commenting out of the while loop.  I've removed the comments now.

Comment: resolved by using Task Scheduler versus a While($True). Removing the loop and having the script run every 15 minutes to check for the condition to trigger an event email.